# Visual Studio - how to chain build of projects with different bitness

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2015

I have a C++ solution with several projects, for example `A` and `B`.
In build process I need several sequential steps:

- `A x32`
- `A x64`
- `B x32`

This needed because results of `A x32` and `A x64` used in pre-build event of `B x32`.

It's easy to force Visual Studio compile `A x32` before `B x32` - just add `A` to `B`'s dependencies. But how we can force Visual Studio to compile `A x64` before `B x32`?

I use Visual Studio 2015

Comment: You could create a batch file that executes msbuild to build the configurations you want in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a "Batch Build" option. Build -> Batch Build. This will support building multiple configurations. Which, as I understand your question, is what you want.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651644.aspx) is the MS link.

I don't think you can add this permanently to the solution/project configuration.